# How can I automatically restart a process after it terminates?

Tags: debian, init.d, debian-squeeze

I've got a golang program that I want to restart after it terminates on a Debian Squeeze box.  The thing is serving HTTP behind an Apache 2 mod_proxy setup.  I don't expect the process to fail, but I'd like to have some insurance against it.

On Ubuntu I would have used upstart to keep the process alive.  Debian doesn't like Upstart from what I understand as it is an init replacement.

Is there an alternative which restarts one or more processes after they terminate that works on Squeeze and plays nice with init?

Comment: Would you please rephrase your question? Is it that you want to restart a process after it has been terminated?

Comment: I'd like to restart a process automatically if it faults or terminates itself.

Comment: The traditional *init* program does precisely this. Why people thought it would be a good idea to use init to run a shell script invoking a shell script that starts another process that does the same thing, but without an automatic kernel panic and reboot should that process ever fail, is completely beyond me.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I'll investigate just using init as well.  I'm packaging the software using dpkg so creating init scripts shouldn't be a hardship.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to go for it are the `daemontools`. They allow you to monitor and respawn processes.

See the documentation on their website: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

Comment: Thanks - that's just what I'm after.  DJB = good as a rule.  I should actually have remembered that existed what with spending 5 years looking after qmail!

Comment: Same with me, except that I used to look after djbdns for quite some time.

Answer (score 10):

[supervise](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html) is a lightweight, efficient alternative. Under debian it is packaged in [daemontools](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/daemontools). You can also read this [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/192302/alternative-to-daemontools-djbtools-to-supervise-unix-processes), which lists some supervise criticisms, and mentions [restartd](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/restartd) as another possibility.

Finally, if you want something incredibly easy to setup, I've had great success with [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). It is also [packaged in Debian](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/monit).

Comment: daemontools is awesome; monit is a freaking nightmare of "why the hell won't you start?!?" frustration.

Answer (score 2):

supervise or monit are good for keeping a single process alive. Since you ask for keeping "one or more" processes alive, I would like to plug [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). It is certainly overkill for managing a single process, but if you need to keep track of multiple processes it may be your thing.

Answer (score 2):

The cross distribution way of handling process re-starts is with cron and a simple script. You can see a writeup here [How to keep a job running in Linux](http://servermonitoringhq.com/blog/how_to_keep_a_job_running_in_linux)

The script looks something like

```
#!/bin/bash 
# make-run.sh 
# make sure a process is always running.  
# Add the following to the crontab (i.e. crontab -e)
# */5 * * * * /home/path_to_make_run/make-run.sh

process=servermonitoringhq 
makerun="/home/path_to_the_job_you_want_running/runjob.sh"  

if pgrep $process > /dev/null         
then                 
  exit         
else         
  $makerun &         
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `/etc/inittab` instead of putting your script in `/etc/init.d/`.

You simply add an entry in the following format:

`<jobname>:<runlevels>:respawn:<command>`

Unfortunately this means you cannot use the normal start/stop/restart init commands, but it should ensure your script is running all the time.